# Maximum number of edges $f(n,k)$ in a graph on $n$ vertices with no $k$-core?

Tags: extremal-graph-theory, co.combinatorics

The $k$-core of a finite graph is defined as follows.  Delete all vertices of degree $< k$ and repeat until there are no such vertices left.  If there is a nonempty subgraph remaining, necessarily of minimum degree $\ge k$, we call this graph the $k$-core.  If the deletion process results in removing all vertices, we say that the graph has no $k$-core.

Let $f(n,k)$ denote the maximum number of edges in a simple graph on $n$ vertices with no $k$-core.  For example, if $f(n,2)=n-1$ for every $n$, since $n$ edges are sufficient (and necessary) to guarantee the existence of a cycle.

What about $k \ge 3$?  Maybe a formula is too much to hope for, so for fixed $k$ what are the asymptotics of $f(n,k)$ as $n \to \infty$?

I suspect this kind of question has been studied, so any references would be appreciated.  It is very similar in flavor to questions in ["classical" extremal graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem), where one tries to maximize the number of edges in a graph on $n$ vertices with no $H$-subgraph, where $H$ is a fixed graph.  This question fits in a more general setting where $H$ ranges over an infinite family of possible subgraphs.

Comment: I think you want "of minimum degree >= k".  Also, the literature on triangle free graphs may hint at an answer for f(n,3), even though it will only give an upper bound, and possibly a very weak bound.  If you specialize to bipartite graphs, (I am guessing) you might also find some literature.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.03.01

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> $$f(n,k)= (n-k)(k-1)+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}, \; \mathrm{for} \; n \geq k, $$
>   $$f(n,k) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2},  \; \mathrm{for} \; n \leq k. $$

**Proof:** Every graph with no $k$-core on $n$ vertices contains a vertex of degree $\leq k-1$ which one can delete, obtaining a graph with no $k$-core. Thus $$f(n,k) \leq f(n-1,k) + k-1.$$

The formula now follows by induction. In the base case $n \leq k$ the formula gives the number of edges in the complete graph.

For an example that the bound can be achieved, let $G$ be a graph with $V(G) = \{1,2, \ldots, n \}$ and let the vertices $i$ and $j$ be adjacent if and only if $|i-j| < k$. It is easy to check that $G$ has no $k$-core and has the right number of edges.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not confused, I believe the graphs you are searching for (with a $k-1$ core but no $k$-core, and adding any edge creates a $k$-core) are also called "maximal $(k-1)$-degenerate graphs," see e.g. [the wikipedia article on degeneracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_%28graph_theory%29).

The [paper](http://smc.math.ca/cjm/v22/p1082) "k-degenerate graphs" of Lick and White proves the following:

> Corollary 1: Let $G$ be a maximal $k$-degenerate graph with $p$ points, $p\geq k$.  Then $G$ has $kp-\binom{k+1}{2}$ [edges].